# Using page title as a link to term archive

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, taxonomy

i want to do something like that (pay attention to line 4):

```
$term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'genre1' );
if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
    continue;
echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '">***<?php the_title();?>***</a></li>';
```

but i dont sure how.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right the following is what you need:

```
$term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'genre1' );
// if there is no error print the link
if( !is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
    echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: thank you! this is almost what i looked for..
actually, i have a function that save my post titles as a terms.
so i want that link will display only the specific term  which is also the page title (and not all terms list)
i hope i was clear enough (cause i confusing my self too..)

Comment: in other words: show the term only if he has the same name of page title

Comment: Please paste the whole function.

Comment: are you meant to this function?                             `<?php $terms = get_terms('genre1');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    //Always check if it's an error before continuing. get_term_link() can be finicky sometimes
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'genre1' );
    if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
        continue;
    //We successfully got a link. Print it out.
    echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';

}
echo '</ul>';?>`

Comment: or to the function that save my post titles as a terms?

Comment: Yes, the one saves your terms. It's better to update your question rather than post comment with code.